# Phase shift of the displacement operator

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics

According to my professor, the displacement operator

$D(α)=e^{\alpha a^†−α^*a}$

can be written, "with a simple phase shift", as

$D(α)=e^{i\alpha(a^†+a)}$ which he then proceeds to write as $D(α)=e^{i\alpha x}$, using $x \propto (a + a^†) $

I don't really see how. 
Writing $\alpha = x_\alpha + i p_\alpha$, I get
$D(α)=e^{2i(p_\alpha x - x_α p)}$

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are operators. $\alpha$ is a pure imaginary number which we then call $i\alpha$ with $\alpha$ now real, this is why from eq1 to eq2 we use $\alpha\rightarrow i\alpha$ and $-\alpha^*\rightarrow i\alpha$. Now from eq2 to eq3 we simply substitute $a+a^\dagger$ for $x$ operator. I don't understand why you want to write $\alpha = \ldots$, its just some real constant.

Comment: It's typographic ambiguity.  It's actually an alpha.

Comment: @AliMoh: That should be an answer.

Comment: Ah, it is not general, but a displacement only in the x-direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a$ and $a^\dagger$ are operators. $\alpha$ is a pure imaginary number which we then call $i\alpha$ with $\alpha$ now real, this is why from eq1 to eq2 we use $\alpha→i\alpha$ and $−\alpha^*→i\alpha$. Now from eq2 to eq3 we simply substitute $a+a^\dagger$ for $x$ operator. I don't understand why you want to write $\alpha=\ldots$, its just some real constant.